# Android google play billing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

What billing options could I use to allow users who download my app to have to pay for each additional device they install it on.

My app once purchased runs on tablets devices WITHOUT internet connection. GP allows users to install this on as many devices as they like using the same account details.

Increasingly my app is being used for commercial corporate use and I want a way to insure I get paid when the app is installed by commercial companies more than once. For example a Bar or Hospital has many tablets running my app, but they only paid once.

As far as I can see there is no specific billing to fit my purpose.

One thought was to display some kind of commercial user agreement at startup that stated that for non personal use they would have to purchase licenses directly to allow them to use it legitimately for each additional device they install it on.

This would rely on honesty, so can be ignored.

So my questions are:

Is there a billing method I've overlooked that could handle this situation?
Is there an alternative way to handle this?
Would I be in breach of GP if I had an commercial user agreement that sort of contradicts the GP billing model. eg paid apps can be installed on multiple devices owned by the same user account? And request additional payment for each device its installed on not using billing.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to retrieve, but if so, why not take unique device number ,i think it's called IMEI, into account? If you have a own server. Hope i got your question

Comment: yes you got the right idea apart from as mentioned, the corporate installations have internet turned off, so no way to authenticate.

Comment: they have to have internet in order to download and install the app

Comment: Just so I'm understanding correctly, is your app free or paid? I'm not aware of any way to charge again for a new device if your app is paid, however, there may be a way if your talking about a free app with transactions within the game.